# How to calculate video size given framerate, resolution and color encoding per pixel?

Tags: video, bandwidth

I need to find the file size of a video size that has 1 hour and 45 minutes, 24bit color encoding per pixel and has 1920x1080 resolution.

So my calculations were like this:

```
Total Pixels = 1920 * 1080 = 2073600

Size of Each Frame = Total Pixels * 24 bit = 2073600 * 24 = 49 766 400 bits

Video Length = 1 hour and 45 minutes = 105 minutes = 6300 seconds

Video Size = Framerate * Size of Each frame * Video Length 
           = 24 * 49766400 * 6300 = ‭7 524 679 680 000 bits
```

I don't know how to express the conversion from bits to gigabytes but I just checked the Video Size in gigabytes using a converter and it gave me a result of 875.99 GB. This does not seem right, so I'm asking here if I missed some calculation.

Note: I will need this to know what minimal speed a bandwidth must have to transfer this file in 12 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming there is no compression...**

Converting size form bits to bytes:
`7524679680000 bits` equal `7524679680000/8` bytes = `940584960000 Bytes`.

Converting size from bytes to Giga Bytes:
In computers systems:
`1 KByte = 1024 Bytes`
`1 MByte = 1024 KByte`
`1 GByte = 1024 MByte = 1024*1024*1024 Bytes = 2^30 Bytes`

`940584960000 Bytes` equal `940584960000/2^30 GB` equal `875.988 GB`

Computing required bandwidth (without compression):
`bandwidth = size / time = 7524679680000[bits]/12[sec] = 627056640000 bits/sec`

Converting from `bits/sec` to `Gbit/sec`:
Remark: Bandwidth is usually measured in Giga **bit** per second (not Giga **Byte** per second).
According to [Wikipedia's Data-rate units page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-rate_units#targetText=gigabit%20per%20second%20(symbol%20Gbit,1%2C000%20megabits%20per%20second) Gbit/s is 10^9 bits/sec (not 2^30 bits/sec).
`627056640000 bits/sec` equal `627056640000/10^9 Gbit/sec` equal `627.0566 Gbit/sec`.

Well... with current technology, even RAM bandwidth is too low (assuming you have 2TB RAM, and you try to copy the data in the RAM, it's going to take more than 12 seconds).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The part `627056640000/2^30 Gbit/sec` shouldn't be `627056640000/10^9 Gbit/sec `, because being Gigabit and not gigabyte?

Answer (score 1):

Your math is correct. The number seems large because this is the size of the raw video. Most videos are compressed to take up less space. The size of the video after compression is determined by the setting chosen for compression, such as the codec and acceptable quality/information loss.

> Note: I will need this to know what minimal speed a bandwidth must
>   have to transfer this file in 12 seconds.

It doesn't work that way because both file size and bandwidth are configurable variables. You are trying to solve the equation X = A * B, where both X and A are unknown and you are trying to solving for B.

If you know the bandwidth, you set the compression ratio to match, If you know the file size, you purchases the necessary bandwidth requires. One value need to be fixed.